# Stop other workers whenever a worker return false value

Tags: java, multithreading

I submit many workers run on multi thread. We stop or don't submit other workers if there are any running worker returns false value. Below is my sample class to demo. What should I do in TODO part? Please give me some advice in this issue.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class CompletionServiceTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        ExecutorService cs = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Collection<Worker> tasks = new ArrayList<Worker>(10);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            tasks.add(new Worker(i+1));
        }

        List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>(tasks.size());
        try
        {
            for (Callable task : tasks)
            {
                futures.add(cs.submit(task));
            }

        // TODO
       // Check if any false value is returned
      // Then stop all running tasks, no need to run other tasks anymore
       }           
        finally
        {
            //Cancel by interrupting any existing tasks currently running in Executor Service
            for (Future<Boolean> f : futures)
            {
                f.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new Date()+":Done");
    }
}

class Worker implements Callable<Boolean>
{
    private int number;
    public Worker(int number)
    {
        this.number=number;
    }

    public Boolean call()
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        try
        {            
            Thread.sleep(50000);
            if(number % 4 == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(500000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            System.out.println("Worker Interuppted");
            throw ie;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you studied the example in the javadoc of `ExecutorCompletionService`? That's pretty much exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I played around an came up with this solution, in case you still look for an working example:

```
class CompletionServiceTest {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService es = newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletionService<Boolean> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(es);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) cs.submit(new Worker(i));
        int count = 0;
        while (++count <= 10 && cs.take().get());
        es.shutdownNow();
    }
}

class Worker implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private final int number;

    public Worker(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 + number * 100);
            if (number % 4 == 0) {
                System.out.printf("worker [%d] failed.\n", number);
                return false;
            }
            System.out.printf("worker [%d] done!\n", number);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.printf("Worker [%d] stopped!\n", number);
            throw ie;
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
worker [1] done!
worker [2] done!
worker [3] done!
worker [4] failed.
Worker [9] stopped!
Worker [7] stopped!
Worker [8] stopped!
Worker [5] stopped!
Worker [6] stopped!
Worker [10] stopped!
```

Comment: don't think it will work, since `future.get()` will wait for the first worker to terminate, what is not the case

Comment: OP may not want to immediately shut down the Executor Service. Typically it is an application-wide singleton and serves all needs for concurrent execution. That's why the more verbose variant which explicitly cancels all remaining futures is preferred.